# Standard name for (filter p xs, filter (not.p) xs)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, naming-conventions

Is there some function in haskell that evaluates to (filter p xs, filter (not.p) xs) in one list traversal (here are two) or is there some common name in functional programming for this kind of function?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First look at the type that you need:

```
Prelude> :t \p xs -> (filter p xs, filter (not . p) xs)
\p xs -> (filter p xs, filter (not . p) xs)
  :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

[Hoogle is your friend](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20Bool%29%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%28%5Ba%5D%2C%5Ba%5D%29):

```
Prelude> :hoogle (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
Prelude break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
Prelude span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
Data.List break :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
Data.List partition :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
Data.List span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
```

Now try out the functions:

```
Prelude> break odd [1..10]
([],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
Prelude> span odd [1..10]
([1],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> partition odd [1..10]
([1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10])
```

Comment: Who's going to make the site "Let me Hoogle that for you"?

Comment: Here's how you get the `:hoogle` command in ghci: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle#GHCi_Integration

Comment: Instead of trying them out, you could just click on the hoogle result links and read the docs.

Comment: Thanks for showing how to find it! That is one of the best answer I have ever had.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell calls it [`partition`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3apartition).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want Data.List.partition e.g.

```
partition (>2) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

results in `([3,4,5], [1,2])`